In ReactJS, when using fetch with body: JSON.stringify, it gives me the result in double quotation marks
I am trying to fetch a POST HTTP request with a body that picks up some useState variables' values. However, the response comes back with a double set of quotations. How can I get just a single set of quotations instead of two? Note: the useState values are correct; they are working well. The problem lies in the fetching result.
this is my code:
const getUsers = async () => {
          try {
            const myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

            const data = {
              lastName: lastName,
              email: email,
              name: name,
              password: password,
            };

            const requestOptions = {
              method: "POST",
              headers: myHeaders,
              body: JSON.stringify(data),
              redirect: "follow",
            };

            const response = await fetch(url2, requestOptions);

           
            if (response.status != 200) {
              throw new Error(
                `something went wrong, status code: ${response.status}`
              );
            }
            const users = await response.json();
            return users;
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        };

The response I get is:
"name" : "\"Julieth\"",
    "lastname" : "\"Bautista\"",
    "email" : "\"tierra2@hotmail.com\"",
    "password" : "\"Test123!\""

In my chart looks like double quotation:

I tried to use without the JSON.stringify on the body, but it doesn't work; it throws an error in the fetching process.

Probably there's something wrong on the server side then. Why do you think it's related to fetch, does the same request work when sent by a different client?

Yes, thank you so much! How didn't I see that? Thank you! I was using JSON.stringify again on the server side! Thank you, I appreciate it!

In that case, it's probably best to just delete the question
